# Hibernate's bidirectional OneToOne relationship not working within the same class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create "a chain of commands" using One to One hibernate relationship withing the same class:

```
@Entity
public class Command {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
private Long id;

@ElementCollection
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<String> commandWithArguments = new ArrayList<String>();

private ExecutionStatus status = ExecutionStatus.NOT_EXECUTED;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentCommand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command child;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command parentCommand;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "command")
private ExecutionResult result;

public Command() {
}
....
```

Does hibernate support relationships like this? It throws the following exception during initialization:

```
 Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.dockerhosting.domain.system.Command.child, referenced property unknown: com.dockerhosting.domain.system.Command.parentCommand
```

yet the parentCommand property is not missing as you can see.

I'm using hibernate 4.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are defining two `mappedBy` properties for the same mapping, so Hibernate will get confused in the mapping.

So it's unecessary to use the two of them, you have two choices here:

**1.** To use only one `Command` object inside your class and map it with `OneToOne` like this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command parentCommand;
```

**2.** Or to make it bidirectional use two `Command` objects in your class like you did and map the two of them with `OneToOne` **but** use `mappedBy` only with child to refer the `parentCommand`:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentCommand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command child;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command parentCommand;
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: It's far too different, First of all presents the problem, then shows two ways to solve and to map `OneToOne` relationship, where only the second one is similar to yours.

Comment: I upvoted both answers, but accepted the one by @chsdk since it's somewhat more detailed. Thank you both very much!

Comment: Great, glad it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify who will carry foreign key in your bidirectional relation(the owning side) if parent or child

child will contains reference(FK) of parrent

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command child;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "child", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command parentCommand;
```

Parent will contains reference(FK) of child

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentCommand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command child;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Command parentCommand;
```